# Derivation practical problem rate of change pumping water from cylinder to reservoir

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck at this problem and the solution doesn't make sense to me, I would like to understand what's wrong with my reasoning.

There is a cylindrical tank with height 15m and radius 10m, fluid is being pumped into a biddon, which is composed of a rectangle and a prism (see picture).

[image: Cylindrical and prismatic reservoir]

We know that the liquid level is decreasing with 2cm/sec in te cylindrical tank, and want the rate the level increases in the biddon at a level of 6m

My way of solving is first calculate $V^\prime$.

$V=hr^2\pi$ so
$V^\prime=\pi r^2h^\prime\, \to\, V^\prime=10000(2\pi)=20000\pi$

Then for the body I split up in two parts, 
First  $V=1000(1500h)$

Second $V=(800\cdot1500h)/2$

(I did $\frac{30}{10}=\frac{x}{6}\,\to\,x=18$ and $b=18-10$)

Added them together $V=15\cdot10^5h+6\cdot10^5h \,\to\, 21\cdot10^5h$

Then  $\frac{V^\prime}{21\cdot10^5}=h^\prime$ so $h^\prime=0.01496\,$cm/sec

However the result should be 0.019 cm/s, and it involves the height of the cylinder, but I don't see how that matters, or why my way is wrong.

I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the depth of water in the biddon is $y$ meters the volume $V_B$ will be
\begin{eqnarray}
V_B&=&150y+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(15)(y)(2y)\\
   &=&15y^2+150y
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}V_B=30(y+5)\frac{dy}{dt}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

The water level in the cylinder is dropping at a rate of $0.02$ m/s which means the volume $V_C$ of the water in the cylinder is decreasing at a constant rate of $\frac{dV_C}{dt}=-\pi(10)^2(0.02)=-2\pi\,$m$^3$/sec.

But this means that $V_B$ is increasing at a constant rate $\frac{dV_B}{dt}=2\pi\,$m$^3$/sec.

So to find the rate $\frac{dy}{dt}$ at which the water level is rising in the biddon when $y=6$ we substitute into equation $(1)$ to get

\begin{equation}
2\pi=330\,\frac{dy}{dt}
\end{equation}

and get the solution

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\pi}{165}
\end{equation}

So when $y=6$ m, the water level is rising approximately $0.019$ m/sec or $1.9$ cm/sec.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that the prysm had a length of twice the hight, it all makes sense now

Comment: I'm glad that helped. And welcome to StackExchange. There are two built-in ways you can "like" an answer: You can "like" an answer to your own question by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer which you like best. You can also click the up arrow next to any answer you like even if it is just a good answer but not the best answer.